# Difference between $.each and each()

Tags: json, object, iteration, each

I am looking for an explanation of the difference between `$.each` and the `each` method.

My simplistic understanding is that `$.each` is used when iterating over a string, such as a Json and `each()` when iterating over an object; however since I am self-learning that could be completely wrong.

Comment: You're talking about different things. $.each() means you invoke each method on $ object.

Comment: My understanding is that they are different, and I am looking for an answer on the differences.

Answer (score 1):

`$.each` is a method named [`each` in JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) global variable `$`.

You can declare any `each` method you want and even override jQuery's.

```
$.each = function(selector) {
   // your implementation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) )

A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays. Arrays and array-like objects with a length property (such as a function's arguments object) are iterated by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. Other objects are iterated via their named properties.

```
$.each([ 52, 97 ], function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
});
```

.each( function(index, Element) )

Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.

- foo
- bar

```
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```